# bootstrap multiselect get selected values

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

How do I get back on onChange all selected values in my multiselect dropdown. Used plugin [here](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#options). Trying to use the following but I think I'm on the wrong track

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
        selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        maxHeight: '300',
        buttonWidth: '235',
        onChange: function(element, checked) {
            var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
            var selection = [];
            $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
                selection.push(brand);
            });

            console.log(selection);
        }
    });
```

**found it**

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: '300',
    buttonWidth: '235',
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
            selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

the solution what I found to work in my case

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
    selectAllValue: 'multiselect-all',
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    maxHeight: '300',
    buttonWidth: '235',
    onChange: function(element, checked) {
        var brands = $('#multiselect1 option:selected');
        var selected = [];
        $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
            selected.push([$(this).val()]);
        });

        console.log(selected);
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for a solution however you've got an error in your selected.push statement. you're pushing a list of the option value rather than the value as a string. you want to remove the enclosing brackets.

Answer (score 31):

Shorter version:

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
    ...
    onChange: function() {
        console.log($('#multiselect1').val());
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked in IE11 for me

Answer (score 18):

more efficient, due to less DOM lookups:

```
$('#multiselect1').multiselect({
    // ...
    onChange: function() {
        var selected = this.$select.val();
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Note that it does return an array of all checked values, as some of the other answers are trying to do manually. Null is returned when none are selected.

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#multiselect1').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
    var arrSelected = [];
    selected.each(function(){
       arrSelected.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: It really helped

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#multiselect1').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).find("option:selected");    
    var arrSelected = [];

    // selected.each(function(){
    //   arrSelected.push($(this).val());
    // });

    // The problem with the above selected.each statement is that  
    // there is no iteration value.
    // $(this).val() is all selected items, not an iterative item value.
    // With each iteration the selected items will be appended to 
    // arrSelected like so    
    //
    // arrSelected [0]['item0','item1','item2']
    // arrSelected [1]['item0','item1','item2'] 

    // You need to get the iteration value. 
    //
    selected.each((idx, val) => {
        arrSelected.push(val.value);
    });
    // arrSelected [0]['item0'] 
    // arrSelected [1]['item1']
    // arrSelected [2]['item2']
});
```

Comment: Code is often really helpful, but an explanation to go along with it is often what people are after. Perhaps consider adding something?

Comment: Yes. My explanation is inside Ravshanbek's code fragment. I was remarking on the functionality of the code. I will remember to not do this inside the code next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was using **jQuery validation rules** with

`submitHandler` function and submitting the data as `new FormData(form);`

> Select Option

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="branch" name="branch" multiple="multiple" title="Of Branch" data-size="6" required>
  <option disabled>Multiple Branch Select</option>
  <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
  <option value="Civil">Civil</option>
  <option value="EXTC">EXTC</option>
  <option value="ETRX">ETRX</option>
  <option value="Mechinical">Mechinical</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="new_branch" id="new_branch">
```

Get the multiple selected value and set to `new_branch` input value & while submitting the form get value from `new_branch`

Just replace `hidden` with `text` to view on the output

```
<input type="text" name="new_branch" id="new_branch">
```

> Script (jQuery / Ajax)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#branch').on('change', function(){
          var selected = $(this).find("option:selected"); //get current selected value
          var arrSelected = []; //Array to store your multiple value in stack
          selected.each(function(){
            arrSelected.push($(this).val()); //Stack the value
          });
          $('#new_branch').val(arrSelected); //It will set the multiple selected value to input new_branch
      });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Html page please add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Test the multiselect with ajax</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap multiselect -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <br>

      <form method="post" id="myForm">

        <!-- Build your select: -->
        <select name="categories[]" id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple" class="col-md-12">
          <option value="A">Cheese</option>
          <option value="B">Tomatoes</option>
          <option value="C">Mozzarella</option>
          <option value="D">Mushrooms</option>
          <option value="E">Pepperoni</option>
          <option value="F">Onions</option>
          <option value="G">10</option>
          <option value="H">11</option>
          <option value="I">12</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <button type="button" class="btnSubmit"> Send </button>

      </form>

      <br><br>
      <div id="result">result</div>
    </div><!--container-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap multiselect -->
    <script src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap multiselect -->
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize the plugin: -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect();

      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

In your ajax.js page please add

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".btnSubmit").on('click',(function(event) {
    var formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: "action.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(data)
      {
        $("#result").html(data);

        // To clear the selected options
        var select = $("#example-getting-started");
        select.children().remove();
        if (data.d) {
          $(data.d).each(function(key,value) {
            $("#example-getting-started").append($("<option></option>").val(value.State_id).html(value.State_name));
          });
        }
        $('#example-getting-started').multiselect({includeSelectAllOption: true});
        $("#example-getting-started").multiselect('refresh');

      },
      error: function()
      {
        console.log("failed to send the data");
      }
    });
  }));
});
```

In your action.php page add

```
  echo "<b>You selected :</b>";

  for($i=0;$i<=count($_POST['categories']);$i++){

    echo $_POST['categories'][$i]."<br>";

  }
```